# Positional notation: proof of relations for different base but same digits

Tags: number-systems

I have the following situation:

Be $n_1, n_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ with the notation of $n_1$ in base $b_1$ and $n_2$ in $b_2$ and the digits $z_{l-1}z_{l-2}...z_0$

Furthermore, be $b_1 > b_2$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Proof (or refute) that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that if $l > N$ and $z_{l-1} \neq 0$, then $n_1 > mn_2$.

I think that this implication is correct but I struggle with how to proof it. Does anyone have a tip how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $l$-digit number $n$ in base $b$, we have the following limits: $(\underbrace{100\ldots 0}_l)_b\le n\lt (\underbrace{100\ldots 0}_{l+1})_b$, i.e. $b^{l-1}\le n \lt b^l$.

Now, if we can have $mb_2^l\le b_1^{l-1}$ for a sufficiently large $l$, then, for *any* $l$-digit number $n_1$ in $b_1$ and *any* $l$-digit number $n_2$ in $b_2$ we will have:

$$mn_2<mb_2^l\le b_1^{l-1}\le n_1$$

All that is left is to prove that $mb_2^l\le b_1^{l-1}$ is achievable for sufficiently large $l$. However, this inequality is equivalent with $mb_1\le\left(\frac{b_1}{b_2}\right)^l$, and this is certainly true for "large enough" $l$ because $b_1>b_2$, and so we have that the right-hand side diverges to $+\infty$ (when $l\to\infty$), while the left-hand side is a constant. More explicitly, you may take $l\ge N=\lceil\log_{b_1/b_2}(mb_1)\rceil$.

(Note we have proven the inequality not only in the case $n_1$ and $n_2$ have the same digits, but in the case of them having arbitrary digits, as long as both are with the same *number* of digits and the leading digit is nonzero in both.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not quite sure I understand though why the following inequalities are equivalent: $mb_2^l \leq b_1^{l-1}$ and $mb_1 \leq (b_1/b_2)^l $ . Would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Max Simple algebra: multiply both sides by $b_1$, divide both sides by $b_2^l$.

Comment: Oooh, I was so sure that this task is hard that I didn't even try something so basic^^ Thanks again, this is really helpful!